# dynamically put enpoint url through setup scripts

Tags: soap

I have two Environment and a lot of test cases, but not all test cases are needed to be run in all environment. Is there a way to run only an specific test cases from a test suite based on the selected Environment. in Setup script .I am using soap ui version 5.4.0 For Example If I select Environment1, it will run the following test cases TC0001 TC0002 If I select Environment2, it will run only the following test cases TC0003 TC0004

Here as I am using "testcases.each" its replacing all endpoint url to one env but i want to exceute based on the testcasename.I am  new to the groovy scripting .So can anyone help  on this

I am currently using below code but its replacing all endpoint urls in all test cases::

```
def result = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.prompt("Please select the enviornment", "Environment", ['UAT_API','IT2','UAT1'])
def testcases = testSuite.getTestCaseList()

if(result == 'UAT1'){
testcases.each { testcase ->
    def teststeps = testcase.getTestStepList() 
    teststeps.each { teststep ->
        teststep.setPropertyValue('endpoint','')
    }
}
}else if(result == 'UAT_API'){
                testcases.each { testcase ->
                def teststeps = testcase.getTestStepList() 
                teststeps.each { teststep ->

        teststep.setPropertyValue('endpoint','https://a-api.com')
    }    
}
}else if(result == 'IT2'){
                testcases.each { testcase ->
                def teststeps = testcase.getTestStepList() 
                teststeps.each { teststep ->
        teststep.setPropertyValue('endpoint','https://it-webservices.com:1')
    }    
}
}
```

Can someone give guidance how to proceed from here to?

Comment: Fixed broken formatting and reworded to make the question more clear. Nonetheless you should read [mcve] and see if you can add further descriptions (about what exactly is not working with your code, which parts are unclear).

Comment: I have two Environment and a lot of test cases, but not all test cases are needed to be run in all environment. Is there a way to run only an specific test cases from a test suite based on the selected Environment. in Setup script .I am using soap ui version 5.4.0

For Example If I select Environment1, it will run the following test cases
TC0001
TC0002

If I select Environment2, it will run only the following test cases
TC0003
TC0004

Comment: Dont provide more information in comments, update your question instead. And besides: you are expected to be around after asking a question. The help center is really clear about that. You expect others to spend their time with your problem. So you should be willing to react to feedback given to you quickly, not one week later.